# Sending email with Pdf attachment in Java

Tags: java, jsp, email, pdf

I am Sending email with pdf attachment in Java which is working properly. But when I went to open the pdf file it unable to open and display message "Adobe Acrobat Reader DC could not open 'Report.pdf' beacuse it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged(for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded)".

```
MimeBodyPart attachment = new MimeBodyPart();
    //outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] bytes = outputStream.toByteArray();
    ByteArrayDataSource ds = new ByteArrayDataSource(bytes, "application/pdf");
    attachment.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(ds));
    attachment.setFileName("Report.pdf");
    MimeMultipart mimeMultipart = new MimeMultipart();
    mimeMultipart.addBodyPart(attachment);
    msg.setContent(mimeMultipart);
```